# How to access Controller class variable value in data access layer?

Tags: asp.net-core

Code in appsettings.json:

```
{
   "Logging":{
      "LogLevel":{
         "Default":"Warning"
      }
   },
   "AllowedHosts":"*",
   "ConnectionStrings":{
      "DefaultConnection":"Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=CrudDataBase;User Id=xyy;Password=xyz123###;"
   }
}
```

Code in HomeController:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]

public class EcoSystemHomeController : ControllerBase
{
    EcoBusinessHome ebl= new EcoBusinessHome();
    public string ConnectionString;

    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public EcoSystemHomeController(IConfiguration config)
    {
        this.configuration = config;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public object GetServiceStatus()
    {
        try
        {
            ConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

            JObject StatusObj = new JObject();
            StatusObj.Add(ConnectionString);
            return StatusObj;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

My app follows the three-layer architecture. I have a variable named `ConnectionString` inside `EcoSystemHomeController`. It holds the connection string value. I want to use this `ConnectionString` variable in the data access layer. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Reading AppSettings from AppSettings.json using IConfiguration interface
In the below example, the IConfiguration is injected in the Controller and assigned to the private property Configuration.

Then inside the Controller, the AppSettings are read from the AppSettings.json file using the GetSection function.

Test Code:

```
   private IConfiguration Configuration;

        public TestController(IConfiguration _configuration)
        {
            Configuration = _configuration;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            //ConnectionStrings
            string appName = this.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings")["DefaultConnection"];

            return View();
                
        }
```

Result:

[image]